# how to draw plots without data in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to draw this plot. I know how to do it with data. But here I don't have any data. And I want to draw this. How would I do it?

[image]

Comment: What you need is an expression for the function drawn by these dots. As such, maybe this question would be a better fit for math.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com .

Comment: What you mean by draw plot without data? Do you want the axes only? Do you want to extract the data somehow from the image you have?

Comment: I don't have equation or the data. Is there any way to extract the data from this? Or how to find the equation and plot it?

Comment: @user1280282: The function is given in the metadata for the Wikipedia image you posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have said, if you don't have the data values, you need to generate them using a function. The easiest way is to use PGFPlots and simply plot a function f(x) where x is sampled at regular intervals within some range. For example, to plot f(x)=x^3, you could use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, fill=cyan, mark size=1.5] {x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For more complicated functions, and especially when your x samples aren't regularly spaced, you can either calculate the data outside of TeX and simply include it in your document, or you could use PGFPlotstable to generate a data table inside the document.

Here's an example where I created a table with three columns: x, an intermediate step, and y, based on the code found in the metadata included with the [Wikipedia image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Spearman_fig1.svg) you used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstablenew[
create on use/x/.style={
    create col/expr={rnd}
},
create on use/intermediate/.style={
    create col/expr={ln(\thisrow{x}/(1-\thisrow{x}))}
},
create on use/y/.style={
    create col/expr={
        \thisrow{intermediate}/(abs(\thisrow{intermediate}))*abs(\thisrow{intermediate})^1.4
    }
},
columns={x,intermediate, y}]
{75}
\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, fill=cyan, mark size=1.5] table [x=x, y=y] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't try it for "real" scientific papers, of course. `:-)`

Comment: @T.Verron: Not without adding some noise, of course, otherwise people will get suspicious!